# Is OE "g" iegland from Pgmc "w" or "j" awjōlandą?

Tags: proto-germanic, old-english

Is OE "g" iegland from Pgmc "w" or "j" awjōlandą?

Comment: *\*awjō* has a diphthong followed by [j], *īeġ* has a diphthong followed by [j]. I feel like this doesn't have to be a great mystery even if you can't be bothered to look up what *īe* is the regular outcome of.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Pgmc "w" in awjōlandą is from "gw". Pgmc "gw" changes to g in OE hnigan (Pgmc *hnīwaną) Pgmc  "j" disappears in OE "willa" Pgmc "*willjō"

Comment: @Cairnarvon Pgmc awjōlandą gives Proto-West Germanic: *AUwju https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/awjō

Comment: The Old English continues \*awjōlandą, and whether or not there was a \*g in there at an even earlier stage is irrelevant, because it is lost. And you've been told this before: you need to include your specific concerns in the original question to begin with if you want helpful answers instead of downvotes. This back-and-forth just wastes everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

The Proto-Germanic diphthong *aw regularly becomes ēa in Old English, and īe (West Saxon) or ē (Mercian & Northumbrian) when subject to i-mutation. Followed by a *j, the *aw in *awjōlandą would be subject to i-mutation, giving  īe as the West Saxon reflex of the *aw diphthong, and leaving the ġ in īeġland as the reflex of the *j.

Unfortunately there is a complication.

Following West Germanic gemination we would expect *auwju in Proto-West-Germanic. If this is the case, what happened to the consonantal w here?

It is important to note that reflexes of Proto-Germanic wj are inconsistent within West Germanic, suggesting that there has been widespread analogy. This is not especially surprising, as w cannot appear in coda (except as the off-glide to a diphthong) West Germanic gemination would seem to require an onset wj that only appears after certain diphthongs, a situation that seems likely to be unstable.

In particular, verbs generally preserve the w in all West Germanic languages (at least until it would be lost due to other processes); as these verbs are all causatives in -jan it's likely the w was restored by analogy to the base verb.

Meanwhile, nouns appear with or without the w depending on language: cf Old English frēa "lord" vs Old High German frouwa "lady", and Old English īeġ "island" vs Old High German ouwa "meadow".

In general, Continental West Germanic reduces the wj onset to w (with expected loss of j immediately after another consonant in the same syllable).

Old English is less consistent though. In the case of frēa it appears to be lost entirely, whilst in the case of īeġ it has reduced to j. This may be to do with the different inflectional class (frēa being weak, and īeġ strong) but the exact process behind this is unclear to me.

Comment: Pgmc "w" in awjōlandą is from "gw". Pgmc "gw" changes to g in OE hnigan (Pgmc *hnīwaną) Pgmc "j" disappears in OE "willa" Pgmc "*willjō"

Comment: @Cairnarvon Pgmc awjōlandą gives Proto-West Germanic: *AUwju https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/awjō

Comment: @ДобрыняПростов I've expanded substantially now on the issues surrounding PWGm *auwju